# jQuery off then on chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering why this code would be effective, and if it is not, is there a better way to make sure that event handlers are removed before the new event handler is attached:

```
$('.selector')
        .off('click', '.item')
        .on('click', '.item', function() {
            // code goes here
         })
```

Thank you for help in knowing if this is an optimal way to make sure the event handler has been removed before adding another to the selector.

Comment: It is "effective" as you put it, but... it's almost never needed in well written code. If you need to remove the event and add a new one that doesn't exist, chances are the handler should have been bound directly to the element, where it will be automatically cleaned up once that element is deleted and replaced with a new, or the event handler is written in such a way that it doesn't need to be removed and rebound to work with the new element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a jQuery function that calls this two functions at once:

```
$.fn.onAndOff = function(event, selector, handler) {
  this.off(event, selector)
      .on(event, selector, handler);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$(".selector").onAndOff("click", ".item", function() {
  // code goes here
});
```

Comment: `.off().on()`is easier to understand than `.onAndOff()`

Answer (score 0):

If there's a risk of multiple identical click events being created for a particular element in your app, this may be a solution. Typically, however, the logic of your application is designed to prevent that.